# Accepting Both Array and ArraySlice As the Same Parameter in Swift

Tags: swift

I am writing a function that accepts both `Array<Int>` and `ArraySlice<Int>` as a parameter. The function relies on comparable elements (actually `Int`) and subscripts with integer indices, which is implied by both `Array` and `ArraySlice`. I was able to find some intersection between these 2 types at `RandomAccessCollection`.

Unfortunately, I can't just use `RandomAccessCollection<Int>`: (The error is next: "Cannot specialize non-generic type 'RandomAccessCollection'"). Instead I had to do next long-winded declaration:

```
func functionName<T>(
  arr: T
) -> T.Element where T: RandomAccessCollection, T.Element: Comparable, T.Index == Int {
  // implementation
}
```

I would like to simplify the function declaration if possible. Ideally I would like to make it as clean as receiving arrays would be: `func functionName(_ arr: [Int]) -> Int`). Is it possible?

Underlying reason to accept both types is next: when writing an algorithm, the function often accepts an array, but needs to make recursive call to itself with array slice. Because it's ugly to restrict public API of the function to `ArraySlice`, you either have to fiddle with generics (as described above) or create nested function that accepts array slice and call it instead (or create new array from array slice which doesn't feel right either). Both options create some unnecessary complexity to otherwise simple function.

Comment: You *can* use `RandomAccessCollection<Int>` with the constraints `T: RandomAccessCollection, T.Element == Int`. But a recursive function taking an array slice and a wrapper function taking an array is the good, simple solution.

Answer (score 4):

Creating an `ArraySlice` from an array is cheap - O(1), so convert the original array into an `ArraySlice` for the first function call, and then deal just with `ArraySlice`s.

You can also overload the method to accept both:

```
func functionName(arr: [Int]) -> Int {
   functionName(arr: arr[...])
}

func functionName(arr: ArraySlice<Int>) -> Int {
   // ...
}
```

Comment: That's another option. Overloading does adds boilerplate to the solution though.

Comment: @Ossir You don't have to overload, but it helps by hiding the implementation details of  ArraySlice from your API layer (i.e. the ArraySlice taking function could be made private)

Answer (score 1):

You can declare it by ArraySlice, right?

```
func functionName<T: Comparable>(arr: ArraySlice<T>) -> T {
    
}
```

Then with the whole array, you can pass arr[0..<arr.endIndex].

Array -> ArraySlice has time complexity is O(1)

Comment: I like the answer. The thing to note here, that limiting parameter to `ArraySlice` only is bad for API design. Considering that at each call site it's necessary to convert an array to a slice now.